# Transforming Data to Common Zero in Excel

Tags: excel, data-analysis

I have a dataset which has some low-frequency noise within it. I've tried a highpass filter at the point where the data is generated, but it causes too much overhead and the signal gets too attenuated. The image below is a sample of what is recorded. What I'd like to do is have the orange line straight horizontal.
[image: Sample Data]

When processing the data, I drop a line parallel to the y-axis until it hits the orange line and calculate the length of it. That works fine for data processing, but for presenting the information I would rather have the line on the bottom flat so they can just focus on the height of the peaks.

Any suggestions for how to do that?

EDIT:
[Rough drawing of the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0BWK.png)

Comment: Can you show how you would like it to appear, or is that what you already showed?

Comment: What is shown is how it looks now. What I'd like is for that bottom orange line to be straight all the way across. Let me see if I can make a quick drawing and I'll update the original post.

Comment: So do you need to snap the bottom blue to the same value as the horizontal orange? Is the question how to get the same bottom value for blue, or rather, just have an orange line at the smallest blue value?

Comment: The question is how to adjust the blue line so that the bottom point on all of them is the same. That would transform/stretch/squeeze the shape of the blue line, in my mind. I considered taking a valley-to-valley grouping and using the slope of each orange line segment and then adjust each point on the blue line in that group and then come back after and align all of the groupings at the end, but that seems like a lot of manual steps.

Comment: Yeah, regardless of approach I think your data will be skewed if modifying your blue points. For presentation, maybe it depends what story you're trying to tell. One option is just make the orange line an avg value of the valleys. Good luck.

Comment: You write you want the orange line to be straight, but none of your drawings show a straight orange line.  Perhaps what you really want to do is connect the different nadirs by straight lines?

Comment: Take a look at the "Rough drawing of the desired output" image at the end of the original question.